# Image hover displaying all images at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm working with Jquery and attempting to create a hover effect. The end result is simply hovering over a `<h2>` elements and a single feature image should appear for the respective element content group. However multiple images appear at once where it should only be one image. Heres working [pen](http://codepen.io/ssosina/pen/zZmQXM)

**HTML**

```
<p>Hover over titles</p>

<div class="content1">
  <h2>Title 1 goes here </h2>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports" alt="Image"/>
</div>

<div class="content2">
  <h2>Title 2 goes here </h2>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/people" alt="Image"/>
</div>

<div class="content2">
  <h2>Title 3 goes here </h2>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/technology" alt="Image"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('h2').on('mouseenter mousemove', function(evt){
        $('h2,img').css({left: evt.pageX+30, top: evt.pageY-15}).show();
        $(this).on('mouseleave', function(){
            $('img').hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Why are all the images showing at once? and how can I resolve it to only show the one image in context?

Thanks!

Comment: try  `$(this).next('img').css({left: evt.pageX+30, top: evt.pageY-15}).show();`

Comment: This worked too! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're telling it to show all images at once on the `h2` event. Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('h2').on('mouseenter mousemove', function(evt){
        $(this).siblings('img').css({left: evt.pageX+30, top: evt.pageY-15}).show();
        $(this).on('mouseleave', function(){
            $(this).siblings('img').hide();
        });
    });
});
```

You can see it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/zaj200mL/

Comment: Its really strange but this doesn't work after visiting other site pages and returning back to the index page where this jquery is used. However it works after a page refresh but issue still persists after visiting other pages.

Comment: I don't think that's an error with this code, sounds like something else is causing your issue. The code above does what you asked for in your question @samsos

Comment: I'm using [this](https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js) but can't see where the issue could occur

Comment: Does the code above work fine when you're not using that library? @samsos

Comment: Damn. I should have performed that obvious check. It works well. Your code is not the problem. I apologies

Comment: No problem at all @samsos :)